# Django Error: You can't set dateOfBirth (a non-nullable field) to None

Tags: django, mongodb

I'm using Django-nonrel with mongodb. I have the following model:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField()
    address = AddressField();
```

I also a serializer for this model:

```
class PatientSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    firstName = serializers.CharField()
    lastName = serializers.CharField()
    occupation = serializers.CharField()
    gender = serializers.CharField()
    dateOfBirth = serializers.DateField()
    address = AddressField();

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new patient
        """
        return Patient.objects.create()(**validated_data)
```

Finally, I'm using the view:

```
def patient_list(request):
    # Create a new patient 
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = PatientSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

I send this JSON request:

```
{"firstName":"Yasir","lastName":"Khan","occupation":"Engieneer","gender":"male","dateOfBirth":"2016-08-09","address":"1, avenue Rosa Parks"}
```

When I try this, I get an error saying that dateOfBirth is none:

IntegrityError at /records/
You can't set dateOfBirth (a non-nullable field) to None!

```
IntegrityError at /records/
You can't set dateOfBirth (a non-nullable field) to None!
```

I can't see where the error is, as you can see, dateOfBirth is not really empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem occurs in create method within your serializer (assuming that there is no typo in the code you have posted here)

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    """
    Create and return a new patient
    """
    return Patient.objects.create()(**validated_data)
```

In your return statement you're not passing validated_data to create method. Try changing it to

```
return Patient.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Other fields in your model have specified default values, therefore Django is complaining only about dateOfBirth.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately it did'nt work. Still have the same error.

Comment: I tried to set a default value to dateOfBirth, it now works correctly, thanks !